# Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list' Code Igniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-query-builder

So I want to insert some data in my database that has `timestamp` in it, but when I insert the data it keeps telling me `Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'`  although I don't have any variable , function or table column called `created_at`. This has been bugging me for several hours

Everything except that function that has timestamp is working fine

PurchaseOrderView :

```
<?= $this->extend('layout/template'); ?>
<?= $this->section('content'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Purchase Order</h1>
            <br>
            <h4>Insert data Purchase Order</h4>
            <form method='POST' action="/purchase">
                <?= csrf_field(); //*csrf secure 
                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="suppid">Supplier id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="suppid" name='suppid' placeholder="Check Supplier ID on Supplier Product Page">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prodid">Product Id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodid" name="prodid" placeholder="Check Product ID on Product Page">
                    <small id="prodidhelp" class="form-text text-muted">Empty if want to add new product</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="newprodname">New Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newprodname" name="newprodname">
                    <small id="newprodnamehelp" class="form-text text-muted">Input new product name if you want to add new product</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="purprice">Purchased Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="purprice" name="purprice" placeholder="Check Product ID on Product Page">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="qty">qty</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="discount">discount</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount" name="discount">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <? print_r('data'); ?>
        <div class="mx-auto">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">id</th>
                        <th scope="col">supplier id</th>
                        <th scope="col">supplier name</th>
                        <th scope="col">product id</th>
                        <th scope="col">product name</th>
                        <th scope="col">qty</th>
                        <th scope="col">discount</th>
                        <th scope="col">dpp price</th>
                        <th scope="col">ppn price</th>
                        <th scope="col">total price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['email'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $row['address'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?= $this->endSection('content'); ?>
```

PurchaseOrderController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\ProductModel;
use App\Models\PurchaseOrderModel;
use App\Models\SupplierModel;

class PurchaseOrderController extends BaseController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->PurchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrderModel();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        // $model = new PurchaseOrderModel();
        // $dataProduct = $model->get();
        // dd($dataProduct);
        // return view('/pages/Purchase', ['data' => $dataProduct]);
        return view('/pages/Purchase');
    }

    public function insert()
    {
        $product = new ProductModel();
        $purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrderModel();
        $supplierId = $this->request->getVar('suppid');
        $productId = $this->request->getVar('prodid');
        $newProductName = $this->request->getVar('newprodname');
        $purchasedPrice = $this->request->getVar('purprice');
        $qty = $this->request->getVar('qty');
        $discount = $this->request->getVar('discount');
        if ($productId == null || $productId == 0) {
            $price1 = $purchasedPrice * $qty;
            $discountValue = $discount / 100;
            $discountedCalc = $price1 * $discountValue;
            $discountedPrice = $price1 - $discountedCalc;
            $dppValue = 100 / 111;
            $ppnValue = 11 / 100;
            $dppPrice = $dppValue * $discountedPrice;
            $ppnPrice = $ppnValue * $dppPrice;


            $totalPrice = $discountedPrice - $ppnPrice;

            $data = [
                'supplier_id' => $supplierId,
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'product_name' => $newProductName,
                'purchased_price' => $purchasedPrice,
                'qty' => $qty,
                'discount' => $discount,
                'dpp' => $dppPrice,
                'ppn' => $ppnPrice,
                'total' => $totalPrice,
                'purchased_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            ];
            $purchaseOrder->newProduct($data);

            $data2 = [
                'supplier_id' => $supplierId,
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'purchased_price' => $purchasedPrice,
                'qty' => $qty,
                'discount' => $discount,
                'dpp' => $dppPrice,
                'ppn' => $ppnPrice,
                'total' => $totalPrice,
                'purchased_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            ];

            // number_format((float)$dppPrice, 2, ',', ''),
            $purchaseOrder->create($data2);
        } else {
            $priceItem = $product->getPriceItem($productId);

            $price1 = $priceItem * $qty;
            $discountValue = $discount / 100;
            $discountedCalc = $price1 * $discountValue;
            $discountedPrice = $price1 - $discountedCalc;
            $dppValue = 100 / 111;
            $ppnValue = 11 / 100;
            $dppPrice = $dppValue * $discountedPrice;
            $ppnPrice = $ppnValue * $dppPrice;

            $totalPrice = $discountedPrice - $ppnPrice;


            $data = [
                'supplier_id' => $supplierId,
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'purchased_price' => $purchasedPrice,
                'qty' => $qty,
                'discount' => $discount,
                'dpp' => $dppPrice,
                'ppn' => $ppnPrice,
                'total' => $totalPrice,
                'purchased_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            ];

            // number_format((float)$dppPrice, 2, ',', ''),

            // dd($data);
            $purchaseOrder->updateQty($data);
        }
        // dd($totalPrice);


    }
}
```

PurchaseOrder Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use APP\Models\SupplierProductModel;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
use App\Models\ProductModel;
use Exception;

class PurchaseOrderModel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'purchase_order';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'supplier_id', 'product_id', 'product_name', 'purchased_price', 'qty', 'discount',
        'dpp', 'ppn', 'total', 'purchased_at', 'name', 'price'
    ];
    protected $useTimestamps = true;

    public function get()
    {
        $model = new PurchaseOrderModel();
        $data = $model->findAll();
        return $data;
    }


    // public function getAll()
    // {
    //     $builder = $this->db->table('purchase_order');
    //     $builder->join('supplier', 'supplier.id = purchase_order.supplier_id');
    //     $builder->join('product', 'product.id = supplier.product_id');
    //     $builder->select('product.name,purchase_order.qty,product');
    // }

    public function newProduct($dataInserted)
    {
        $modelProduct = new ProductModel();
        $productId = $dataInserted['product_id'];
        $builder = $modelProduct->table('product');
        $data = $builder->where('id', $productId)->first();
        if (!$data || $dataInserted['product_id'] == null) {
            $modelProduct->table('product');
            $id = $modelProduct->first();
            // $newId = $id['id'] + 1;
            // $dataInserted['product_id'] = $newId;
            $newProduct = [
                'supplier_id' => $dataInserted['supplier_id'],
                'name' => $dataInserted['product_name'],
                'qty' => $dataInserted['qty'],
                'price' => $dataInserted['total']
            ];
            // dd($newProduct);
            $modelProduct->save($newProduct);
        }
    }


    public function updateQty($dataInserted)
    {
        $modelPO = new PurchaseOrderModel();
        $modelProduct = new ProductModel();
        $builder = $modelProduct->table('product');
        $data = [
            'supplier_id' => $dataInserted['supplier_id'],
            'name' => $dataInserted['name'],
            'qty' => $dataInserted['qty'],
            'price' => $dataInserted['total']
        ];
        $check = $builder->where('id', $dataInserted['id'])->first();
        if ($check) {
            $qtyNew = $data['qty'] + $check['qty'];
            $data['qty'] = $qtyNew;
            $builder->set($data);
            $builder->where('id', $dataInserted['id']);
            $builder->update();
            return $modelProduct->affectedRows();
        }
    }

    public function create($dataInserted)
    {
        // dd($dataInserted);
        $modelPO = new PurchaseOrderModel();
        $modelProduct = new ProductModel();
        $builder = $modelPO->table('purchase_order');
        $builder->save($dataInserted);
    }
}
```

Product Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['supplier_id', 'name', 'qty', 'price'];


    public function get()
    {
        $model = new ProductModel();
        $data = $model->findAll();
        return $data;
    }

    public function getPriceItem($suppProId)
    {
        // dd($suppProId);
        $builder = $this->table('product');
        $priceItem = $builder->where('id', $suppProId)->first();
        if ($priceItem != null) {
            return $priceItem['price'];
        } else {
            throw new PageNotFoundException('Product with id Suplier not found.');
        }
    }

    // public function insertnewProduct($dataInserted)
    // {
    //     $model = new ProductModel();
    //     $builder = $model->table('product');
    //     $data = $model->save($dataInserted);
    //     dd($data);
    // }
}
```

the `Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'` error is at

```
    $purchaseOrder->create($data2);
```

in the `PurchaseOrderController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PurchaseOrderModel**

```php
$useTimestamps = true;
```

> This boolean value determines whether **the current date is automatically added** to all inserts and updates. If `true`, will set the current time in the format specified by `$dateFormat`. This requires that the table have columns named `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` in the appropriate data type.

codeiniter documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=dateFormat#usetimestamps

Comment: Thankyou It worked after I remove that !